# Installing RVM on Ubuntu 10.10 error

Tags: ubuntu, rvm

I'm trying to do this:

```
bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

but I keep getting this error

```
bash: line 1: html: No such file or directory
bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'ash: line 2: `<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
```

What's going on?

Comment: That command is to install RVM, not Rails. Which are you trying to install?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The URL to install RVM was recently changed to use HTTPS, so the command is now:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

However, you should always **read the [up-to-date RVM installation docs](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/)** for the current command.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://rvm.io/rvm/install, that's not the correct URL.  It should be...

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while trying to install rvm on osx. I finally got it working by downloading the "rvm" file from https://rvm.io/install/rvm and running it, like this: sh rvm

Answer (score 0):

If you https://get.rvm.io you will get redirected to rvm-installer link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer then you can replace the curl command with:

```
\curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable
```